# What's the recommended number of Kafka connectors for a large database ? (Debezium)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I'm trying to set up Debezium for data change monitoring in this huge database.

[Documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/) says *"Debezium can monitor any number of databases. The number of connectors that can be deployed to a single cluster of Kafka Connect services depends upon upon the volume and rate of events. However, Debezium supports multiple Kafka Connect service clusters and, if needed, multiple Kafka clusters as well."*

However, there's no mention about how many connectors is a good practice.

Reading mediums and some use cases, it seems like one connector for a whole database is a suitable option. But if we have a lot of tables and a lot of changing events in a fraction of time, it should become a bottleneck. Or not? I've seen people working with one connector per table too. It would mean a LOT of connectors in this case. If you have an use case concerning heavy databases along with Debezium, could you tell your experiences about connectors ?

(The source database, in this case, are mostly postgres)
Sorry if it's a dumb question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I used to whitelist tables using regex like this `"table.include.list": "^(DATABASE_NAME.)([A-I][A-Z\\,_]*)*$"`, it means debezium will look for the tables which start from A to I. and deploy the other debezium connectors like this.

Comment: @AchyutVyas Hi, thank you for your answer! How many tables did you use to include in every connector ? (I was wondering if this takes a lot of processing but following Debezium docs, "any table not included in table.include.list does not have its changes captured" so I guess Debezium really ignores everything about the other tables).

Comment: It depends on your table's data that how many table's you want to add in your connectors and how many debezium connector's you want to deploy, I usually deploy three debezium connectors with different `table.include.list` like for `debezium-mysql-1` `"table.include.list":"^(DATABASE_NAME.)([A-I][A-Z\\,_]*)*$"` for `debezium-mysql-2`  `"table.include.list":"^(DATABASE_NAME.)([J-R][A-Z\\,_]*)*$"` and for `debezium-mysql-3` `"table.include.list":"^(DATABASE_NAME.)([S-Z][A-Z\\,_]*)*$"`

`debezium-mysql-1` connector will read tables which name starts with A to I.
_(1/2)_

Comment: `debezium-mysql-2` connector will read table which name starts with J to R.
and `debezium-mysql-3` connector will read table which name starts with S to Z.

this approach is used to distribute producer load among multiple connectors.
_(2/2)_